# Can I get golden or silver tools if I am not the mayor? (other user) Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I played Animal Crossing New Leaf with a cousin. I have not started playing it before my cousin started playing... He became mayor and I was the side character (other player). He doesn't play anymore and I play my other player but I really want the gold axe and I have not got it yet. So can I really get golden tools when I am not the mayor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as long as you have the special circumstances,http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/golden-and-silver-tools/, you should be able to obtain it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get gold and silver tools as long as you indeed do and understand the special circumstances to getting them for e.g

Golden Rod- Catch all fish
Golden net- Catch all bugs
Golden Slingshot- Appears randomly in the sky
Golden shovel- Buy 50 fertilizer from T And T Emporium
Golden Axe- Buy 50 Saplings from T And T emporium
Golden Can- get a perfect town status for 15 days straight.